# Font-awesome class with multiple different icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to create custom font-awesome class with multiple icons in it, i.e.
.2star class consisting of 2 stars and 3 empty stars in a line, beside each other. Is there a way to do it in CSS or I have to use html-only solution with multiple i-classes ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you create a custom font awesome class, with multiple characters in content like this

```
.class:after {
   content: "\f005\f005\f005"; /* 3 Stars */
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmqaR/)

Note that the values like `\f005` etc can be found in FontAwesome stylesheet so copy the unicode of the type of font you like and use it in the content property with the font family of Font Awesome.

Comment: Thanks, It's working like a charm. Funny thing is, I've tried it already and it didn't worked because I used a class name which began with number. Well, at least I learned 2 new things in one go:)

Comment: Well that works. Any way to add spacing or margins between each font? They're pretty squished together by default.

Comment: @MattyPantaloons Yes, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content) :) or if you want space between the stars then either use before after and main element or you can add a space code like http://jsfiddle.net/rmqaR/36/