# content property in CSS

Tags: css, css-content

In some template I see that an arrow that created with CSS. something like this:

```
div:after{
    content:"\f107";
}
```

this code display an arrow like  this :

[image]

what is this code? where I can find more codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `content` property embeds a virtual content inside an element, it is used with a pseudo `:before` or `:after`, so if you use `:before`, the content will be embedded before.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) :

> The `content` CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after`
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
>   using the `content` property are *anonymous* [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Replaced_element).

Content property can hold any [character](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wtrf/1/), [number](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wtrf/2/), [entities](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wtrf/3/). For more information, you can refer an article [here](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/).

Also, you can get an handy converter [here](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/08/css-javascript-character-entities/).

---

This method is also used by [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450616/font-awesome-class-with-multiple-different-icons/17450729#17450729) and other related svg font embedding libraries, where you can simply call classes to the elements and the fonts will be embedded virtually.

---

Also, just a side information, content generated using CSS `content` property is `inline` by default, also this is rendered [inside](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wtrf/) the element and not outside..

Answer (score 5):

It's an [escaped unicode character](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/61703/UTF-8-character).

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have explained, the CSS rule uses the `content` property to insert a character by its Unicode number.

However, the character used is U+F107 PRIVATE USE CHARACTER-F107. This means that it has no meaning except by private agreements and should not be used in public information interchange. Unfortunately, some “awesome” tricks use Private Use code points to insert graphic symbols. This means that unless a very specific font, with some symbols assigned to those code points is used, a generic symbol of an unknown character appears.

So it is much safer to use an image instead, in the content proper.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a property called `content`. It can only be used with the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before`. It is written like a pseudo selector (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding something new to the page.

Font Awesome is a web font containing all the icons from the Twitter Bootstrap framework, and now many more.

You can find a list of `FontAwesome` here : [A list of Font Awesome icons and their CSS content values](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

You can also go through this link, [FontAwesome Examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/), where you can see different icons and how to apply different size on it.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Content Property :**  The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

[Read more](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)

Comment: this is not about content, this is about content character codes