# Use Font Awesome icon as CSS content

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to use a Font Awesome icon as CSS content, i.e.,

```
a:before {
    content: "<i class='fa...'>...</i>";
}
```

I know I cannot use HTML code in `content`, so is it only images left?

Comment: From memory you can't inject HTML into the DOM using the content attribute. Just plain old text.

Answer (score 765, accepted):

**Update for FontAwesome 5**
<sup>Thanks to [Aurelien](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20782368/20782415#comment90387622_20782415)</sup>

You need to change the `font-family` to `Font Awesome 5 Brands` OR `Font Awesome 5 Free`, based on the type of icon you are trying to render. Also, do not forget to declare `font-weight: 900;`

```css
a:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f095";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/4633/)

You can read the rest of the answer below to understand how it works and to know some workarounds for spacing between icon and the text.

---

**FontAwesome 4 and below**

That's the wrong way to use it. Open the font awesome style sheet, go to the `class` of the font you want to use say `fa-phone`, copy the content property under that class with the entity, and use it like:

```css
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/87/)

Just make sure that if you are looking to target a specific `a` tag, then consider using a `class` instead to make it more specific like:

```css
a.class_name:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

Using the way above will stick the icon with the remaining text of yours, so if you want to have a bit of space between the two of them, make it `display: inline-block;` and use some `padding-right`:

```css
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

Extending this answer further, since many might be having a requirement to change an icon on hover, so for that, we can write a separate selector and rules for `:hover` action:

```css
a:hover:before {
    content: "\f099"; /* Code of the icon you want to change on hover */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/165/)

Now in the above example, icon nudges because of the different size and you surely don't want that, so you can set a fixed `width` on the base declaration like

```css
a:before {
    /* Other properties here, look in the above code snippets */
    width: 12px; /* add some desired width here to prevent nudge */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/980/)

Comment: See here for [the official list of Unicode character codes in Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

Comment: With `font-family: FontAwesome;` it changes the font for anchor tags also. How can we handle that?

Comment: @Shubh read the code carefully, `font-family` is suppose to be called on `:before` pseudo and not anchor tag

Comment: Just thought I'd add here that you can find the unicode spec for a particular icon without having to dig into the source.  Simply go to the list of icons on the font awesome website and click the icon you want.  You'll see the Unicode value on the page just beneath the samples of the icon:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/pencil-square-o/

Comment: This CSS Unicode list for FontAwesome is better: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/ because it shows the correct `content` codes for direct copying (i. e. a no-brainer). PS: I still wonder why the FontAwesome guys do not put the content codes onto each icon page?!

Comment: Small correction: <<Do not forget to add "font-weight:900;">>...  that's only if you want it to look fat/bold. I've got "font-weight:500;" and I'm very happy with it. I also notice this gives me the <Regular> style, not the <Solid> style (both same Unicode codepoint according to their website).  I'd rather have <Solid> but I'm not sure how to access.

Comment: Here is Font-awesome docs page that shows you how to use it going forward. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: @user3445853 why 500? According to the Demo, I can't see the icon with 500, only with 501 and above, I don't get it.

Comment: Why do we need `font-weight: 900` ? If I ommit font-weight then it happens to render nothing but a empty square

Comment: updated link for fontawesome 5 official list  https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Comment: A couple of things to note here: 1. If you're seeing a square when changing `font-weight`, it means that the icon you're trying to render isn't free for that particular `font-weight`. 2. I've found that removing the `vertical-align: middle` looks better (at least for the FA 5 version and at least in my case).

Answer (score 27):

Another solution without you having to manually mess around with the Unicode characters can be found in *[Making Font Awesome awesome - Using icons without i-tags](http://dusted.codes/making-font-awesome-awesome-using-icons-without-i-tags)* (*disclaimer: I wrote this article*).

In a nutshell, you can create a new class like this:

```
.icon::before {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .5em;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

And then use it with any icon, for example:

```
<a class="icon fa-car" href="#">This is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 25):

If you have access to SCSS files from font-awesome, you can use this simple solution:

```
.a:after {
    // Import mixin from font-awesome/scss/mixins.scss
    @include fa-icon();

    // Use icon variable from font-awesome/scss/variables.scss
    content: $fa-var-exclamation-triangle;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You should have font-weight set to 900 for **Font Awesome 5 Free** font-family to work.

This is the working one:

```css
.css-selector::before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
   content: "\f101";
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. really !

Answer (score 10):

```
a:before {
     content: "\f055";
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     left:0;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
}
```

Example Link:
https://codepen.io/bungeedesign/pen/XqeLQg

Get Icon code from:
https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io

Answer (score 4):

You can use unicode for this in CSS. If you are using font awesome 5, this is the syntax;

```
.login::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f007";  
}
```

You can see their documentation [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements).

Answer (score 1):

As it says at FontAwesome website [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) =>

HTML:

```
<span class="icon login"></span> Login</li>
```

CSS:

```
 .icon::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }

    .login::before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f007";
   }
```

In `.login::before` -> edit `content:'';` to suit your unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Font Awesome 5 using SCSS

```
.icon {
  @extend %fa-icon;
  @extend .fas;

  &:before {
    content: fa-content($fa-var-user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my webpack 4 + font awesome 5 solution:

webpack plugin:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', to: 'font-awesome' }
  ]),
```

global css style:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svgfontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

i {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```