# How to style prev/next arrows button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

> **GOAL**

I've been trying to modify the `slick.css` to fit the style I need in my site.
I got the `slick.css` from [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

**Now**

- I want to make the arrow (left + right) bigger
- For icons, I want to use the one with no `circle-border` around it.
- I like `fa-chevron-right` and `fa-chevron-left`

---

> **What have I tried ?**

portion of `slick.css`

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next { position: absolute; display: block; height: 200px; width: 50px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; cursor: pointer; background: transparent; color: transparent; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; }
.slick-prev:hover, .slick-prev:focus, .slick-next:hover, .slick-next:focus { outline: none; background: transparent; color: transparent; }
.slick-prev:hover:before, .slick-prev:focus:before, .slick-next:hover:before, .slick-next:focus:before { opacity: 1; }
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before, .slick-next.slick-disabled:before { opacity: 0.25; }

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: "slick"; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; color: red; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }



.slick-prev { left: -10px; top: 70px;  }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev { left: auto; right: -10px; top: 70px; }
.slick-prev:before { content: "←"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before { content: "→"; }

.slick-next { right: -10px; top: 70px; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next { left: -10px; top: 70px; right: auto; }
.slick-next:before { content: "→"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before { content: "←"; }
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="row slick ">
// just a bunch of lists in here
</div>
```

---

**Detail Photo**

Here is what I have now.

[image]

Here is what I want to have.

[image]

---

> **Question**

- Can someone help me resolve this ?

  I really appreciate your consideration and time. :)

Comment: could you post your relevant html too please? =)

Comment: why don't you use font-awesome library ..and use fa-angle-* icon instead..  http://jsfiddle.net/qfMdP/26/

Comment: @mikelt21 : I add some HTML base on your request. Check it out.

Comment: @AlokBhat : I want to use it, but how do I do that on my css file ? Can you answer your idea.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Basic thing is its producing  arrows by content property:

```css
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: "slick"; font-size: 40px; line-height: 1; color: red; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }   

.slick-prev:before { content: "‹"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before { content: "›"; }

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next { left: -10px; top: 70px; right: auto; }
.slick-next:before { content: "›"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before { content: "‹"; }
```

Replace these classes and after that just play with margin and positions properties to adjust the arrows,  if this didnot fix the issue send me the http://jsfiddle.net/ link i will send you the complete solution.

If want to use Font Awesome

```css
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: FontAwesome; font-size: 40px; line-height: 1; color: red; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }   

.slick-prev:before { content: "\f053"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before { content: "\f054"; }

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next { left: -10px; top: 70px; right: auto; }
.slick-next:before { content: "\f054"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before { content: "\f053"; }
```

For list of Font icons visit http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/
and how to implement the font visit this thread
[Use font awesome icon as css content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content)

Comment: The `<` + `>` doesn't look that well. What should I do if I want to use font awesome for [`>`](fa-chevron-right). Can you help me with that ?

Comment: there are so many free icon font out there, just google it and apply to your element `.slick-prev {font-family:xxxxxx}`

Comment: You can use: in this way i am updating my answer see the solution over there

Comment: I like your update. Thanks for that. May I ask where you get `\f054` from ?

Comment: Visit this page under neath you will get all the codes: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Answer (score 7):

```css
.slick-prev::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0d9";
    font-size: 22px;
}  
.slick-next::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:  "\f0da";
    font-size: 22px;        
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="slick-prev "></button>

<button type="button" class="slick-next "></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sass you can set sass variables provided by slick.

Refer: [Add custom buttons on Slick Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043562/add-custom-buttons-on-slick-carousel/41894956#41894956)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.responsive_com2').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots:true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        rows: 1,
    });

    $('.left_news').click(function(){
        $('.responsive_com2').slick('slickPrev');
    })

    $('.right_news').click(function(){
        $('.responsive_com2').slick('slickNext');
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: <div>
    <div class="right_news">
     
      
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_Left_news" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
  y="0px" viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
        .st_Right{fill:#c5960c;}
          .st_Right:hover{color:#ffffff;}
        </style>
<g>
 <polygon class="st_Right" points="2.9,9.8 2.3,9.1 6.4,5 2.3,0.9 2.9,0.2 7.7,5.1  "/>
</g>
</svg>
      
    </div>
 right arrow code comes here
    </div>
</div>