# Add custom buttons on Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

How do I apply custom prev and next buttons to slick carousel? I have tried a background image on the `.slick-prev` and `.slick-next` css classes. I have also tried adding a new class as per the documentation but the arrows disappeared completely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.big-image').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  nextArrow: '.next_caro',
  prevArrow: '.previous_caro'
});
</script>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because they use an icon font for the buttons, you need to replace the whole button code. Or you can go here http://fontastic.me/ and create your own icon font

Comment: I just made a more complete anwser, mark it as correct to help improve Stack Overflow

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but maybe I can be of help to someone, bc this also stumped me until I read the documentation a bit more:

> prevArrow string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery
>   object) Previous
>   Allows you to select a node or customize the HTML for the "Previous"
>   arrow.
>
> nextArrow string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery
>   object) Next Allows
>   you to select a node or customize the HTML for the "Next" arrow.

this is how i changed my buttons.. worked perfectly.

```
  $('.carousel-content').slick({
      prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-left.png'>",
      nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-right.png'>"
  });
```

Comment: you do not need the css class for the image, slick slider will add a class for handling the click action

Comment: I have tried this, but it's not working. Actually, I am using slick by cdn links, so could this be the reason that I am not able to use my own customization

Answer (score 23):

**[From the docs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**

> **prevArrow/nextArrow**
>
> **Type:** `string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery object)`

**Some example code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slick-carousel-1').slick({
        // @type {string} html
        nextArrow: '<button class="any-class-name-you-want-next">Next</button>',
        prevArrow: '<button class="any-class-name-you-want-previous">Previous</button>'
    });

    $('.slick-carousel-2').slick({
        // @type {string} jQuery Selector
        nextArrow: '.next',
        prevArrow: '.previous'
    });

    $('.slick-carousel-3').slick({
        // @type {object} DOM node
        nextArrow: document.getElementById('slick-next'),
        prevArrow: document.getElementById('slick-previous')
    });

    $('.slick-carousel-4').slick({
        // @type {object} jQuery Object
        nextArrow: $('.example-4 .next'),
        prevArrow: $('.example-4 .previous')
    });
});
```

**A little note on styling**

Once Slick knows about your new buttons, you can style them to your heart's content; looking at the above example, you could target them based on `class` name, `id` name or even `element`.

**[Did somebody say JSFiddle?](https://jsfiddle.net/kstoddard/f8o1mm44/)**

Comment: My company has been using slick for years and no one knew we could place our own buttons in the dom. We've been annoyingly using position:absolute; with your first example for far too long. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 11):

if you want to use icons from any icon font library, you can try this in the option while calling the slider in your js file.

```
prevArrow: '<div class="class-to-style"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Prev</span></div>',

nextArrow: '<div class="class-to-style"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></div>'
```

Here "fa" comes from FontAwesome icon font library.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, you can use the Glyphicons.

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings", "slick", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.slick-prev:before { content: "\e257"; }
.slick-next:before { content: "\e258"; }
```

Comment: worked for me but because of font size I had to additionaly add `.slick-prev, .slick-next { width: 40px; height: 40px; }`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me when a lot of these other items did not:

```
.slick-prev:before {
  content: url('your-arrow.png');
}
.slick-next:before {
  content: url('your-arrow.png');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you cant use default CSS classes and add some your style?

```
.slick-next {
  /*my style*/
  background: url(my-image.png);
}
```

and

```
.slick-prev {
  /*my style*/
  background: url(my-image.png);
}
```

Are you used simple **background** css property?

in example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BNvke/1/

You can use **Font Awesome** too. Don't forget about CSS pseudo elements.

And don't forget jQuery, you can replace elements, add classes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sass you can simply set below mentioned variables to use icons provided by other fonts,

```
$slick-font-family:FontAwesome;
$slick-prev-character: "\f053";
$slick-next-character: "\f054";
```

These will change the font family used by slick's theme css and also the unicode for prev and next button. This example will use FontAwesome's chevron-left and chevron-right icons.

Other sass variables which can be configured are given in [Slick Github page](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because they use an **icon font** for the buttons. They use "Slick" font as you can see in this image:

[image]

Basically, the make the letter "A" the form of an icon, the letter "B" the form of another one and so on.

For example:

[image]

*If you want to know more about icon fonts **[click here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/icon-fonts/)***

If you want to change the icons, you need to replace the whole button code or you can go to **[www.fontastic.me](http://www.fontastic.me)**  and create your own icon font. After that, replace the font file for the current one and you'll have your own icon.

Answer (score 1):

its very easy. Use the bellow code, Its works for me. Here I have used fontawesome icon but you can use anything as image or any other Icon's code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        autoplay:true,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev pull-left'><i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
        nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next pull-right'><i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  speed: 500,
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: false,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  slide: 'div',  
    nextArrow: '<button id="next">Next >',
        prevArrow: '<button id="previous">previous >',  
    
  
});
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

A variation on the answer by @tallgirltaadaa , draw your own button in the shape of a caret:

```
var a = $('.MyCarouselContainer').slick({
    prevArrow: '<canvas class="prevArrowCanvas a-left control-c prev slick-prev" width="15" height="50"></canvas>',
    nextArrow: '<canvas class="nextArrowCanvas a-right control-c next slick-next" width="15" height="50"></canvas>'
});

function drawNextPreviousArrows(strokeColor) {
    var c = $(".prevArrowCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.moveTo(15, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(15, 50);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    var c = $(".nextArrowCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(15, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawNextPreviousArrows("#cccccc");
```

then add the css

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next 
    height: 50px;s
}
```