# font awesome content coming as blank for IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, font-awesome

*Browser*: My application renders as IE7 Mode(Document Mode)

I have a similar requirement as Deka87 had for [Use font awesome icon as css content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content). Now, when I implement the solution given by Mr. Alien I get a weired problem.

CSS Class:

```
.listing th.sort-col-d{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0dd";
}
```

This when rendered in browser, makes the `content=" "`. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVR04.jpg)

[image]

When I check my network tab then the font awesome request is successful and I can see the Response Body. It even changes the font for the `th` element.

I am not sure what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from the **font-awesome** website: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

> If you need IE7 support, you have my condolences. Really. Font Awesome
>   4.4.0 doesn't support IE7, but an older version does. You'll need to check out the 3.2.1 instructions for using IE7. Then go complain to
>   whomever decided your project needs IE7 support.