# Ruby: Place Font Awesome inside text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield, font-awesome

Please help me with this simple question. I did not found any answer.

I have this text_field_tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i><%= text_field_tag 'ip', "", maxlength: 15, class: "form-control" %></div>
```

I want to place font awesome inside my text_field_tag, but..

What happen is, the icon is display outside from the text_field_tag

[image]

Actually I know why this happen, because the font awesome is outside form the text_field_tag. I try to place font awesome inside the text_field_tag but get an error.

What is the right way to place the font awesome inside the text_field_tag?
Hope anyone can answer this simple question.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="input-group">
  <%= text_field_tag 'ip', "", maxlength: 15, class: "form-control" %>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I got the idea, but need to change just a little line of code. anyway thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `form-control` width is set as `100%`. You will have to change that manually and set its `display` to `inline`.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 someclass"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i><%= text_field_tag 'ip', "", maxlength: 15, class: "form-control" %></div>
```

CSS

```
.someclass i {
  display: inline;
}
.someclass .form-control {
  display: inline;
  width: 95%;
}
```

These CSS should be given in `application.css` where you `import bootstrap`. Otherwise you will have top give `important!` to each attribute in the `form-control` css.

Comment: Hi @sajinmp. This is not the answer that I'm looking for. What are you doing is just make the font awesome and text_field_tag in one line.

what I want is I want the font awesome put inside the text_field_tag. Do you have any idea to make the font awesome INSIDE the text_field_tag besides making the icon and text_field_tag in one line?

thank you

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content

Answer (score 1):

#### Add an Icon to the Right Side of a Bootstrap Search Bar

I had a similar problem where I wanted to add a search icon into the right side of a Bootstrap 4.1 search bar.

I had this:

[image]

But I wanted this:
[image]

I was able to resolve it by adding positioning to the icon via a new class I'm calling `search_icon`.

Add a `search_icon` class to your `<i>` element:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x search_icon"></i>
  <%= text_field_tag 'ip', "", maxlength: 15, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Style the new class:

```css
.search_icon{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 25px;
  right: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
}
```

Credit goes to Rafi Benkual [whose CodePen](https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/rFgcI) tipped me off for the icon styles.