# Angular-material - Change separator in md-select multiple option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

I have an md-select in my form with multiple options (same as [demo in Angular Material site](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select)). It shows a comma separated list of selected options in its input field. Is there any way to change separator? (for example change comma to star or another UTF-8 character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something with pure CSS. You should hide the commas using `visibility: collapse` and after that, you can add a Unicode icon with `:after` or `:before` pseudo-element.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/mkYWRo597YCo36zgNcai?p=preview)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<md-select class="my-select" ng-model="vm.selectedItem" multiple>
  <md-option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">{{ item.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-select[multiple] .md-select-value span:first-child {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.my-select[multiple] .md-select-value .md-text {
  display: inline-block !important;
  visibility: visible;
}

.my-select[multiple] .md-select-value .md-text:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '\2605'; /* star */
  margin: 0 -5px 0 5px;
}
```

---

*There you go a [list of Glyphs](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/) that you can use. 

Also, you can [add a font-awesome icon with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content) if you want.*

Comment: for me, the template code generated does not have the comma character as the content for :after pseudo selector, hence it is not able to target it using the :after selector.

Comment: @Prime could you share your version of angular material so I can update my answer if that possible?

Comment: Thanks. Little imporvement: first selector should be `.my-select[multiple] .md-select-value span:first-child:has(>div)`. In other case it hides title for select if nothing selected.