# Replace md-select separator character

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

When md-select is used with multiple option, and multiple options are selected it separates the them using commas. I want to apply custom styling to the selected options which are being displayed and therefore want to get rid of the automatically added comma characters. 
I checked [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724777/angular-material-change-separator-in-md-select-multiple-option) but it is not working for me, the accepted answer, targets those characters(i.e commas) by using a pseudo selector `:after` but the template code which md-select generates for my code is not able to be targeted by this pseudo selector `:after`, the reason for that is the commas are not a part of `md-text`'s content.

Below is the generated template code which md-select value is selected

```
<md-select-value class="md-select-value" id="select_value_label_62"><span><div class="md-text ng-binding">
Option1
</div>, <div class="md-text ng-binding">
Option2
</div>, <div class="md-text ng-binding">
Option3
</div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value>
```

I want to get rid of the commas placed after ending `div` tags. The commas are not wrapped in any html tag with which I can target them and that makes me stuck in this situation since I cannot style them in anyway using CSS. 
 
Their only wrapper tag is `md-select-value` and this cannot help in targeting those sparsely placed commas. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`md-selected-text` API](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#attributes) ([demo from the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select#selected-text)). Note that there is also an API for `md-selected-html`.

Here's a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wu9cEaeqY2DY9U71) using the `|` separator char with `md-selected-text`.