# Select2, multiple selection tags, change template without modifying core

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 for tags. The plugin prepends `&times;` as a crude X to remove the tags. I really don't like this and I want to use one of my icons `<i class="icon icon-remove"></i>` in place of this. Unfortunately in the documentation I cannot find any information on how to override this behavior.

You can, for example use `templateSelection` to change the way the tags are presented, but the plugin still prepends the times icon (functionality I want, just with a different style).

Is there a way to modify the template without changing the core file? If so, can anyone provide me with an simple example?

I located it here:

```
  MultipleSelection.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
    var $container = $(
      '<li class="select2-selection__choice">' +
        '<span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">' +
          '&times;' +
        '</span>' +
      '</li>'
    );

    return $container;
  };
```

BTW I am using [Select2 4](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js).

Comment: hi did you find a way to do this? i want to add an extra button

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to change the template. you can simple style ahead with CSS.

you could give `.select2-selection__choice__remove {font-size: 0}` and add your custom icon on `.select2-selection__choice__remove:after` selector.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think that will subvert the point of the icon as it will no longer remove the tag as select2 looks for `select2-selection__choice__remove` clicks

Comment: of course, you have to keep that button.
and style it with display block, width and height so that it is still clickable.

use the icon-font like it's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content