# Fontawesome leaf symbol not working while dot symbol works in ::before content usage in css

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Credits & thanks to Alex Raven for his autogenerated collapsible directory tree (**ACDT**) in [https://codepen.io/asraven/full/qbrgje](http://https//:codepen.io/asraven/pen/qbrgje).

I want to put *tree symbol* before a node (text) in tree if node is a parent and *leaf symbol* if node has no child.

I loaded FontAwesome files (Font Awesome 5 Free) to achieve this and **I edited only last part of the css** of ACDT.

Edited part is the part below comment "The icons" in css.

I could not make leaf icon visible for leaf nodes.

`\f06c` represents leaf icon.

It's weird that I can see dot-circle symbol if I write `content: "\f192";` under `ul.directory-list li::before`; however if I write `content: "\f06c";` in same place it's not working.

My browser is IE11, I have to use this only browser.

At worst I can solve my issue at PHP side however I want to understand "why" and solve with CSS if possible. What is the reason & how can I solve this issue? Can you help me. Thanks.

my only edited part of css, html and full css are given below:

**Only edited part of css**

```
/* Only edited part */

ul.directory-list li::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  
  font-style: normal;
  content: "\f06c"; /* \f192 is working, \f06c not working*/
  margin-right: 10px; 
}
ul.directory-list li.folder::before {
  /* folder icon if folder class is specified */
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  
  font-style: normal;
  content: "\f1bb"; /* \f1bb is working, \f06c also works*/
  margin-right: 10px;  
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome-all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"/>  
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Collapsible Directory List</h2>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="directory-list">
    <li>assets
      <ul>
        <li>css
          <ul>
            <li>typography.css</li>
            <li>layout.css</li>
            <li>modules.css</li>
            <li>states.css</li>
            <li>theme.css</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>js
          <ul>
            <li>custom.js</li>
            <li>jquery.js</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>images
          <ul>
            <li>logo.svg</li>
            <li>arrow-sprite.svg</li>
            <li>social-sprite.svg</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>functions.php</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>templates
      <ul>
        <li>pages
          <ul>
            <li>about.tpl</li>
            <li>pricing.tpl</li>
            <li>contact.tpl</li>
            <li>home.tpl</li>
            <li>features.tpl</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>header.tpl</li>
        <li>menu.tpl</li>
        <li>footer.tpl</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>index.php</li>
    <li>style.css</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
<i class="fa">&#xf06c;</i>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/folder_tree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom.css**

```
/* Demo page styles
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "times new roman", serif;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h2 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 30px 5%;
  padding: 5%;
}

@media (min-width: 544px) {
  .box {
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 440px;
    padding: 40px;
  }
}


/* The list style
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.directory-list ul {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.directory-list li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.directory-list a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.directory-list a:hover {
  border-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

.directory-list .folder,
.directory-list .folder > a {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* The icons
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Only edited part */

ul.directory-list li::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  
  font-style: normal;
  content: "\f06c"; /* \f192 is working, \f06c not working*/
  margin-right: 10px; 
}
ul.directory-list li.folder::before {
  /* folder icon if folder class is specified */
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  
  font-style: normal;
  content: "\f1bb"; /* \f1bb is working, \f06c also works*/
  margin-right: 10px;  
}
```

Comment: does `<i class="fas fa-leaf"></i>` work?

Comment: yes, it works. I have `<i class="fa fa-leaf"></i><i class="fa">&#xf06c;</i>` ìn html file and i see leaves

Comment: I tried with `<i class="fas fa-leaf"></i>` now and it works also. (Mine previous trial was with `fa` instead of `fas`.

Comment: I think you have to add `font-family: FontAwesome;` to were you are using the unicodes.

Comment: Yeah the new font awesome uses `fas` instead of `fa`, but are you fine with using `<i class="fas fa-leaf"></i>` or do you still wanna know why it's happening and/or use unicodes?

Comment: I have `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";` in my css.

Comment: In this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content/28846011)  post they say you have to use the `font-family` on the place were you use the `content: "\999"`