# Add a space in CSS content

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a button with a [Font Awesome icon as content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content). That works perfect. Problem is that the text following it has no space between the font awesome icon and the text. How can I add a space to the content?

```
a:before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f095 --a &nbsp; here --";
display: inline-block;
```

}

Comment: Will a margin or padding not work?

Comment: Can yoyu provide an example

Comment: You can try letter-spacing in CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_letter-spacing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For CSS content `&nbsp;` use `\a0`. The following is a list of different types of spaces and their CSS code:

- space: `\20`
- nbsp: `\a0`
- en space: `\2002`
- em space: `\2003`
- 3 per em space: `\2004`
- 4 per em space: `\2005`
- 6 per em space: `\2006`
- figure space: `\2007`
- punctuation space: `\2008`
- thin space: `\2009`
- hair space: `\200a`
- zero width space: `\200b`
- narrow nbsp: `\202f`
- medium mathematical space: `\205f`
- zero width nbsp: `\feff`

### Demo

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

a::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
}

#x0::before {
  content: "\f095";
}

#x1::before {
  content: "\f095\20"
}

#x2::before {
  content: "\f095\a0"
}

#x3::before {
  content: "\f095\2002"
}

#x4::before {
  content: "\f095\2003"
}

#x5::before {
  content: "\f095\2004"
}

#x6::before {
  content: "\f095\2005"
}

#x7::before {
  content: "\f095\2006"
}

#x8::before {
  content: "\f095\2007"
}

#x9::before {
  content: "\f095\2008"
}

#xa::before {
  content: "\f095\2009"
}

#xb::before {
  content: "\f095\200a"
}

#xc::before {
  content: "\f095\200b"
}

#xd::before {
  content: "\f095\202f"
}

#xe::before {
  content: "\f095\205f"
}

#xf::before {
  content: "\f095\feff"
}

#x0::after {
  content: "\a0\a0"
}

#x1::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\20"
}

#x2::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\a0"
}

#x3::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2002"
}

#x4::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2003"
}

#x5::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2004"
}

#x6::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2005"
}

#x7::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2006"
}

#x8::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2007"
}

#x9::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2008"
}

#xa::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\2009"
}

#xb::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\200a"
}

#xc::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\200b"
}

#xd::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\202f"
}

#xe::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\205f"
}

#xf::after {
  content: "\a0\a0\\feff"
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<a href='#/' id='x0'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x1'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x2'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x3'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x4'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x5'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x6'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x7'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x8'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='x9'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xa'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xb'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xc'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xd'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xe'>CALL</a>
<a href='#/' id='xf'>CALL</a>
```

Comment: If there are characters after the whitespace codes which are not displayed correctly this may be solved by adding zeros at the beginning to a length of 6 digits -> `\2002`-> `\002002` https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Answer (score 0):

you can add `padding-right:10px;` or whatever `padding` for right or left that you prefered

```
a::before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f095\a0";
display: inline-block;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add spacing with the inbuilt `fa-fw` class

Use like this

```
<i class="fa fa-close fa-fw"></i>
```