# HTML tag inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, font-awesome

Every time I loop through this foreach, a dropdown gets set with database values. When a table has a value for `name` it keeps it's value when it is empty; it doesn't show anything. That's good. But every time a name is displayed, I want a FontAwesome icon in front of `this.name`. Example `<i class="fas fa-car">`. 
How do I get this HTML tag in-between `text:` and `(this.name ?` ?

```js
processResults: function (data, params) {
    var results = [];
    jQuery.each(data, function () {
        results.push({
            id: this.id,
            text: (this.name ? this.name + ' ' : '')
                + (this.firstname ? this.firstname + ' ' : '')
                + (this.middlename ? this.middlename + ' ' : '')
                + (this.lastname ? this.lastname + ' ' : '')
                + ' (' + this.email + ')',
        });
    });
    return {
        results: results,
        pagination: {
            more: false
        }
    };
}
```

I got the question to put a bit of HTML in my question so here you go :)

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="users">{{ trans('messages.receiver') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select id="users" title="Search users" multiple class="form-control" name="user_ids[]"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just putting it there, in single quotes, with a plus sign, after `text:`?

Comment: What's `processResults`?  Are you using [tag:datatables]?  What sort of "drop down" is it?  A simple `<select>` or a [tag:select2] (for example)?

Comment: You could set text to something like: `text: "<i class='fas fa-car'>" + (this.name ? this.name + ' ' : '') +...` but that might not give you the results you want depending on how you're using `results`. Do you have some HTML you can show?

Comment: + (this.firstname ? this.firstname + ' ' : '') should be + ('<i class="fas fa-car"></i> '+ this.firstname ? this.firstname + ' ' : '') your essentially concatenating the string together like you would normally..

Comment: @hereticmonkey I have indeed tried that, without succes. When I do that it just shows it as a string and it is added with all the other options like firstname middle name etc.

Comment: @freedomn-m don't worry about `processResults` it is part of a bigger function, this just a small pievce from the function. And yeah I use `<select>`

Comment: The issue is that you can't add HTML to an `<option>` inside a `<select>` - you can with [tag:select2] or other drop down replacement.  So if you're using `<select>`, you're out of luck.

Comment: That is good information to have *in the question*, as it would have prevented a good deal of wasted time. As would letting people know of any frameworks, libraries, etc. that you are using, up front (see [ask]). Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions a day, and you have a limited window in which your question will be seen by people. Waiting 15 hours to respond to comments is unlikely to help that. Just a tip from someone who's been around for a while :).

Comment: @hereticMonkey Sorry, I was busy sleeping. Like many people do. Asked the question right before i got off of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard value of `.select2` is that it can't display HTML tags.

You can overwrite this by adding:

`escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  },`

at the top. This will overwrite it's value of not recognizing HTML tags.

Now you can add the wanted HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also fix this problem with css
You can add a fontawesome icon in front of the name with some css styling by using a before.

The link here is an old bookmark of mine, where you can find an example in the approved answer.

[Use font awesome icon as CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782368/use-font-awesome-icon-as-css-content)