# How to use Glyphicons in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I am using Bootstrap 4. I would like to use **Glyphicon** in my own class like below.

.my_class {
content: "\e253";
}

How can I use that ?

Answer (score 1):

Glyphicons has been deprecated in bootstrap 4, you can use fontawsome instead, check the attached comment link for an example on using fontawsome, try it and it will achieve what you seek to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20782415/5710264

Answer (score 1):

- Use `::before` pseudo class
- Use `glyphicon` class

**Note:** Same applies for font awesome also

```css
.my_class::before {
  content: "\e253";
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="glyphicon my_class"></span>
```